# How to make a dynamic grid view using Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, sencha-touch

I want to make a grid view, and the number of rows and column will be user input. How sencha touch(preferably 2.3) can help me there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [Touch Grid](http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-touch-2-3-html5-for-ios7-touch-grid-cordova-support-more) - that's what it's for. It's part of Sencha Complete which gives you the whole bundle of Sencha products (disclosure: I work for Sencha).

Comment: What about "Touch Grid is available as part of Sencha Complete or the Sencha Touch Bundle." does this means it is only available buying a package ?

Comment: Yes, you have to buy it.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Sencha Complete" is having the Touch Grid support. For free gpl users, see https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.touch.grid

Comment: Is this actually compatible with Sencha Touch 2.3 ?

Comment: Yes,i guess this is compatible with Touch 2.3. I have implemented this in 2.2 .